# Build array of coordinates with Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, maps

I have searched high and low, found some great solutions....but for some reason they do not work for me.

Basically on a div hover event I want to draw a polyline based on the coordinates geo coded and retrieved by database. Now, the console appears to display the array elements fine, but I do think this is the problems I can't find. I think I am passing an incorrectly constructed array to create a `LatLng` object.

So here is my map:

```
wgmpmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("wgmpmap"), mapOptions);
```

Here is my function:

```
function highlightRoute(zip,locationId){
 jQuery.ajax({    
    type: "GET",
    url: "goGetRoute.php?location_id=" + locationId + "&zip=" +zip,             
    dataType: "text",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){ 
        var drivePathCoords = [];
        var tmpCoords = response.split("|");
        for (i = 0; i < tmpCoords.length; i++) {
            var tmpLatLng = tmpCoords[i].split(",");
            drivePathCoords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(tmpLatLng[0], tmpLatLng[1]));
        }
        console.log(drivePathCoords.toString());
        var drivePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: drivePathCoords,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: '#008457',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2
        });
        drivePath.setMap(wgmpmap);
    }//end success function
}); //end ajax call
}
```

Here is the PHP script that AJAX sends a request to (only interested in the first route):

```
 /////First geocode given zipcode
$tmpZip =  json_decode(file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$_GET[zip]"));
$tmpZipLat = $tmpZip->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$tmpZipLng = $tmpZip->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
$fromLatLng = "$tmpZipLat,$tmpZipLng";

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error connecting to mysql');


mysql_select_db("myDB",$conn);
$locMatchesQuery = mysql_query("SELECT location_latitude, location_longitude FROM wp_map_locations WHERE location_id = '$_GET[location_id]'");
if(mysql_num_rows($locMatchesQuery) != 0){
     $rowLocation =  mysql_fetch_array($locMatchesQuery);
     $toLatLng = "$rowLocation[location_latitude],$rowLocation[location_longitude]";


         $outString = "";
         $tmp =  json_decode(file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=$fromLatLng&destination=$toLatLng&mode=driving&alternatives=false&units=imperial"));
        foreach($tmp->routes[0]->legs[0]->steps as $step){
            $tmpLat = $step->start_location->lat;
            $tmpLng = $step->start_location->lng;
            $outString .= "$tmpLat,$tmpLng|";
        }       

    echo rtrim($outString, "|");


 }//End If
 else{

 }//End Else
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your `SELECT` statement. Switch to a supported database interface (e.g. PDO) and use parameterisation to fix this.

Comment: I agree that PDO is the way to go, but you can also use mysqli (since mysql has been deprecated) which is closer to the "style" of mysql statements.

Comment: @Shmoopy - yes, although I advised to someone else recently that either is good, and they discovered that `mysqli_fetch_all()` (something that I imagine might be commonly required) requires another PHP module, `mysqlnd`, to be installed. I don't know whether this is usually included in shared hosting, so I tend to play it safe and go for PDO.

Comment: OP, I am having a hard time pinning down your _exact_ problem. Would you also create a JS Fiddle to illustrate it? Also, do you get any JS errors in your browser console?

Comment: I am using the direction service to return a delimited text response. Then I am using the split function to separate all of the coordinates into an array and the iterating through the array and further splitting the coordinates into lat,lng's. This is all executed on a div mouse over passing some properties as parameter values. Anyway the ultimate goal here is to draw a polyline using the coordinates in the drivePathCoords array....hope that was clear. And no there are no errors in the console...just seems that `drivePath.setMap(wgmpmap);` is not doing its job...not sure why though

Comment: Like i mentioned in the original thread, I think it may be the way I am constructiong the polyline array "drivePathCoords".